# Regex expression for complex password setting angular 8

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, angular8

I tried this expression -

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$
```

This regex will enforce these rules:

At least one upper case English letter, `(?=.*?[A-Z])`

At least one lower case English letter, `(?=.*?[a-z])`

At least one digit, `(?=.*?[0-9])`

At least one special character, `(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])`

Minimum eight in length `.{8,}` (with the anchors)

How will be the regular expression for below requirement.

- Passwords that are 13 characters or longer only require lower case
  letters
- Passwords must contain at least 8 characters
- Passwords between 8 and 13 characters require at least 3 of the
  following 4 categories of characters:

  - Uppercase letters
  - Lowercase letters
  - Numbers
  - Symbols

Comment: Okay, now, why are you trying to tackle such a complex task with so much conditional logic with a single regular expression? there is a famous saying stating that "if you have a problem that you are trying to solve with regex, you have 2 problems now". Why don't you just use good old imperative programming for that? You know... `if (pass.length > 13) { checkPass13(pass) }`, etc. What I'm saying is regex is not a good solution for your problem

Comment: @Nemoden - sounds good

Comment: @Nemoden +1. Anything else than regex will almost always be easier to reason about :)

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709)

Answer (score 0):

While a single regex may not be the most readable / sane way to do this, it's actually rather straightforward:

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(.{13,}|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,12})$
```

I've simply added an alteration on the length so that 13+ chars merely requires `[a-z]` while 8-12 chars (one could omit the upper bound due to ordering) requires the full monty.